# How to set a custom value when gridview CellValueChanging event is triggered?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, devexpress

Trying to do this:

```
    private void myGridViewControl_CellValueChanging(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName != "ColorName") 
        {
            e.Value = "myvalue";

        } 
    }
```

e.value is

> readonly

How to set a custom value when the cell is being edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GridView's [SetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.SetRowCellValue.overloads) method to change the value at runtime:

```
private void myGridViewControl_CellValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Column.FieldName.Equals("ColorName"))
    {
        myGridViewControl.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column, "MyValue");
    }
}
```